# Rails Copying a model with its associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop, database-design

This is just a general question about copying a model with its database assoications.  What is the proper strategy for copying?  what happens if for example an association 3 levels deep fails,  do you delete the parents as well?

Comment: Wrap the whole operation in a transaction. This way you won't have to manually delete anything. If there's an error, then just rollback the transaction and you're done.

Comment: what do you mean by wrap it in a transaction?   like a try catch block?

Comment: He means an activerecrod::transaction!  Basically, all sql operartions either succeed together or are all rolled back if there is an error at any point in the block. Check it out here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html